# Export X509Certificate2 to byte array with the Private key

Tags: c#, x509, x509certificate2

I have an X509Certificate2 certificate in my store that I would like to export to a byte array **with** the **private key**. The certificate byte array has to be so that when I then later would import the certificate from the byte array the private key would have the private key with it.

I have tried many wayes but has not succeded to export the certificate with the **private key**.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);      

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2 cert = store.Certificates[1];

byte[] certBytes = cert.GetRawCertData(); // Obviously does not work!
```

Is it possible to successfully export the certificate with private key to a byte array?

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `Export` function of the `X509Certificate2` class allows you to export
a certificate with the private key to a byte array.

The following code demonstrates exporting a certificate with the private key:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2 cert = store.Certificates[1];

// Export the certificate including the private key.
byte[] certBytes = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12);
```

To secure your exported certificate use the following overload of the `Export` function:

```
byte[] certBytes = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "SecurePassword");
```

**BEGIN EDIT**

To import the certificate use the following code:

```
X509Certificate2 certToImport = new X509Certificate2(arr, "SecurePassword");

// To mark it as exportable use the following constructor:
X509Certificate2 certToImport = new X509Certificate2(arr, "SecurePassword", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
// certToImport.HasPrivateKey must be true here!!

X509Store store2 = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher,
                                 StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store2.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

store2.Add(certToImport);
store2.Close();
```

**END EDIT**

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I still have a problem, when I run your code and import it again I get HasPrivateKey = false. What could be the problem?

Comment: @ErikLarsson: I've updated my answer. Hope, this helps. The property HasPrivateKey is true on my machine. If I open MMC to export the imported certificate I am able to exort the private key, too.

Comment: For anyone finding this thread, note that if you want to export it again you need to set it while importing to be `Exportable`, see the next answer and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358129/cryptographicexception-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state-while-trying/9373407#9373407

Comment: This will throw ```System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Key not valid for use in specified state.'``` for a .NET 4.6.2 console app.

Comment: @EivindGussiåsLøkseth: Where exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: @Hans, the issue I had was not related to a specific .NET version. I had a pfx file with a private key that was not exportable, and that's why the code failed. Unfortunately I couldn't find my comment and delete it after discovering this.

Answer (score 4):

One reason for not getting the private key, could be that it has been marked as "Not Exportable" when it was originally added to CAPI. In that case, I don't believe that is any real way of getting it out.

Comment: No, that only means you need stronger techniques. If it can be used it can be exported.

Comment: @Joshua No, when a certificate is marked as "Not Exportable" it can only be used to sign/decrypt your input through the operating system and the operating system returns the result. Therefore the private key can be used but is protected and cannot be exported.

Comment: @fjch1997: Attach a debugger to lsass sometime.

Comment: @Joshua It's not managed code that handles the private key when you get your certificate from the certificate storage

Comment: @fjch1997: Meh. When you use a kernel debugger you prefer native code anyway.

Comment: @Joshua Did a quick google search and there are indeed tools to peek into the memory and retrieve the private key. Thumb down to Microsoft for this...