# Export a certificate from Azure cloud service

Tags: .net, azure, x509certificate

I have a certificate uploaded to Azure. I also lost the original certificate on my machine (oops!).

Now I need to restore the certificate exporting it from Azure cloud service.

This code running in the context of the cloud service gets the correct certificate:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var certificate = store.Certificates
    .Cast<X509Certificate2>()
    .SingleOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.Thumbprint, "<THUMBPRINT>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

But when I try to export the certificate (X509Certificate2.Export), it throws an exception:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key not valid for use in specified state.

Is it possible to export it anyway?

Comment: It's possible the certificate is installed marked as not exportable.

Comment: you have to mark the private key exportable or else you cannot export a PFX in the way you are trying rigth now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358129/cryptographicexception-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state-while-trying

Comment: I had added an answer indicating looking at the Get-AzureCertificate PowerShell Cmdlet, but Gaurav correctly indicated that won't work if you need the cert back out with a private key.  I have removed the answer since it's not correct.

Comment: @ramiramilu How can I make it exportable?

Comment: I don't think you can. These certificates are installed by the Windows Azure platform as it starts up the VM. If it installs them marked as not exportable there isn't much you can do.  You may be at a point where you need to create a different cert.  Not sure.

Comment: @MikeWo, for security reasons it should work this way. But may be there is some way to extract the certificate using Azure management API for example?

Comment: That is what I looked at using the Get-AzureCertificate for. It calls the management API, but as Gaurav pointed out to me that only retrieves the public key and not the entire cert.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Remote Desktop on your Web/Worker Role, connect to it and then you can use Mimikatz to recover the certificate (incl. the private key), **even if it's marked as not exportable**.

Mimikatz (guide is in french): http://blog.gentilkiwi.com/mimikatz/crypto#exportCertificates