# How Can I Combine Multiple .p12 Certificates Into One .pfx file

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate2

I have a large number of single certificates stored as files with .p12 extensions.  I would like to combine all those certificates into one .pfx file to make less work out of importing all those certificates on client machines.
Here is what I have tried.  It creates the file, but the problem occurs when I import the .pfx file.  The Windows Certificate Import Wizard only imports the first certificate and ignores everything after that.  I assume because there is something wrong with the format of the file cause by the way I am attempting to combine them.  I'm not sure of the correct way to do this. Any ideas?

```
private void btnCombineCerts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    String timeString = DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmssff");
    String path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\certs\CombinedCerts\";
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    List<X509Certificate2> certs = new List<X509Certificate2>();
    foreach(var certFile in fDialog.FileNames)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile);
        certs.Add(cert);
    }
    foreach(X509Certificate2 cert in certs)
    {                
        byte[] certStream = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path + dateString + "CombinedCerts" + timeString + ".pfx", FileMode.Append))
        {
            stream.Write(certStream, 0, certStream.Length);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PFX inherently supports multiple certificates, but it isn't a sequential file like what you wrote. I don't know that the UI will import this properly, but it probably will if everything has a private key. The one real use of X509Certificate2Collection is that it can export or import.

```
var certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();

foreach (var certFile in fDialog.FileNames)
{
    certs.Add(new X509Certificate2(certFile));
}

byte[] oneBigPfx = certs.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, oneBigPfx);
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you. I also will mention that the Export method takes a password parameter which is an additional bonus.

Comment: In my case, running the above code for two certificates, I got the (german) error message `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Schlüssel ist im angegebenen Status nicht gültig.`. Translated this reads `Key not valid for use in specified state.`. Seems you [have to specify the "Exportable" enum flag in the c'tor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9373407/107625) to avoid the error. Works even for certs with no password; simply specify an empty string then.

Answer (score 0):

```
public X509Certificate2 Merge(List<X509Certificate2> certificates)
{
    var certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();

    foreach (var certFile in certificates)
    {
        certs.Add(new X509Certificate2(certFile));
    }

    byte[] data = certs.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);

    X509Certificate2 newFile = new X509Certificate2(data);

    return newFile;
}
```