# Getting Error "Key not valid for use in specified state."

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt, token, jose

I am getting `Key not valid for use in specified state.` error while decoding the token from Jose.Jwt.Decode method. Jose.Jwt is a third party library I am using for JWT token encryption & decryption.

```
var privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

var payload = JWT.Decode(token, privateKey, JweAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP_256, JweEncryption.A256GCM);
```

I tried to find this error on internet, but not getting any correct solution. Looking for a perfect one.

Comment: Could you show how you're creating `certificate.PrivateKey`?

Comment: @devNull I have installed .pfx and .cer as certificate on my system.

var certificate = _certificateProvider.GetCertificate(certificateSubjectName);

public X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string subject)
        {
            return Find(subject, StoreLocation.CurrentUser) ?? Find(subject, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        }

Comment: Do you use `new X509Certificate2` anywhere in your code? Maybe in the `Find` method you mentioned above? Also, feel free to edit your original question with any relevant code instead of adding it in comments

Comment: @devNull No i did not used new X509Certificate2 in Find method.   

  private X509Certificate2 Find(string subject, StoreLocation location)
        {
            using (var store = new X509Store(location))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
                var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subject, true);
                return certs.OfType<X509Certificate2>()?.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

Comment: Okay. I was taking a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358129/cryptographicexception-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state-while-trying) for a similar issue. They were able to resolve it by passing `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` as an argument in the `X509Certificate2` constructor. I'm looking to see if there's a way to do the same through the `X509Store`, but I believe you would need to use something similar

Comment: @devNull i have to use jose.jwt.decode method, since the encryption is performed by the same kind of library of java (nimbus-jose-jwt).
Is there any other way to achieve the same.