# RSA - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Key not valid for use in specified state

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I am making a c# project in visual studio for my university. I'm having issues with RSA encryption. When trying to decrypt a string, i get the error

`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Key not valid for use in specified state.`

the code I use is:

```cs
public class RsaEncryptionService
{
    private static RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
    private RSAParameters _privateKey;
    private RSAParameters _publicKey;

    public RsaEncryptionService()
    {
        _privateKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);
        _publicKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);
    }

    public string GetPublicKey()
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, _publicKey);
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    public string GetPrivateKey()
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, _privateKey);
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    public string Encript(string plainText)
    {
        csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        csp.ImportParameters(_publicKey);
        var dataBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
        var cypherData = csp.Encrypt(dataBytes, false);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cypherData);
    }

    public string Decript(string cypherText)
    {
        var dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cypherText);
        csp.ImportParameters(_privateKey);
        var plaintextBytes = csp.Decrypt(dataBytes, false);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plaintextBytes);
    }
}
```

After trying some things out, when I use the Decript method for just a random string it works, but when I use it in this case:

```cs
var rsa = new RsaEncryptionService();
            byte[] text = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.StartupPath + "\\Export\\Export.txt");
            string key = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\Export\\Key.txt");
            string iv = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\Export\\IV.txt");

            var DecryptedKey = rsa.Decript(key);
```

that's when I get the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CryptographicException "Key not valid for use in specified state." while trying to export RSAParameters of a X509 private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358129/cryptographicexception-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state-while-trying)

Comment: I've read it before, but I don't quite understand what I should change in my code. I'm quite new to this and most of this code was picked up from different pages. I'm fairly certain I understand what's wrong, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @GenericUser I'm still stuck on this issue and would be very grateful for further explaination.

Comment: Where/how are you executing this code?

Comment: When I press a button, it takes a string I have prepared and runs the code. The error specifically shows up when decrypting, probably because it uses the private key. The line the error is on is "private RSAParameters _privateKey;".

Comment: You may want to consider calling the constructor the same everywhere. The service has a private member that passes `2048` to `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, while your `Encript` method does not.

Answer (score 0):

Like your `Encript` method, you'll want to assign `csp` to a new `RSACryptoServiceProvider` at the beginning of your `Decript` method.

The Microsoft docs for the [RSACryptoServiceProvider constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.-ctor?view=net-8.0) has an example with this in action:

```cs
public static byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] decryptedData;
        //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            //Import the RSA Key information. This needs
            //to include the private key information.
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

            //Decrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
            //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
            //later.  
            decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
        }
        return decryptedData;
    }
    //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
    //to the console.
    catch (CryptographicException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything, as I still get the same error in the same place. But thank you for your time nontheless.